# Integrate img HTML tag into datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I just started using Datatable and I'm confused about something.
I can't seem to integrate an image HTML tag inside a cell.
It's about the [column.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) I think, but I guess I'm a bit overwhelmed by the doc because I still haven't figured out how to do it.

Here is my code, path return the URL of an image.

```
$('#table_id').DataTable({
   "processing": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "req.php",
        "type": "POST"
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "id" },
        { "data": "path" },
        { "data": "type" },
        { "data": "keywords" }
    ]
} );
```

And what I'm trying to do at the moment.

```
$('#table_id').DataTable({
   "processing": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "req.php",
        "type": "POST"
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "id" },
        { "data": "path" },
            "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
             return '<img src="'+data+'">';
        { "data": "type" },
        { "data": "keywords" }
    ]
} );
```

I'm looking forward to finding someone who can get me out of my ignorance.

Have a nice day :)

Comment: Not quite that. This post is about the same thing but even more confusing than the simple doc that is already confusing me.

Comment: I had flagged this question as a duplicate (hence the comment above). I retracted my duplicate flag after I spotted the real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The render property is outside of the object where your `"data":"path"` is.

You have this code for your rendering now:

```
"columns": [
    { "data": "id" },
    { "data": "path" },
        "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
         return '<img src="'+data+'">';
    { "data": "type" },
    { "data": "keywords" }
]
```

You should rewrite it like this:

```
"columns": [
    { "data": "id" },
    { "data": "path",
      "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
          return '<img src="'+data+'">';
      }
    },
    { "data": "type" },
    { "data": "keywords" }
]
```

Comment: Oh... i feel so dumb now
Thanks ! :)